# Salesforce Get a list of all opportunities which are new, updated or deleted since a given date using api

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I am trying to receive a list of all opportunities that are created/updated/deleted since a given date. When I run query: `SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE SystemModStamp >= '2022-09-20' AND isDeleted = TRUE ALL ROWS` I get a response stating `"message": "ALL ROWS not allowed in this context", "errorCode": "MALFORMED_QUERY"`.

Going over the salesforce documentation I found out using queryAll() api method we can also get the opportunities which are created/updated/deleted. But I am not able to find an example of how to use this api. Any help in this direction would be highly appreciated.

Salesforce queryAll documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_queryall.htm

Comment: how do you want to run this query? Apex controller? SOAP API? REST?

Comment: Hi, I would run as REST API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `queryAll` instead of `query`? Start with

```
/services/data/v54.0/queryAll?q=SELECT+Id,+Name,+isDeleted,+StageName+FROM+Opportunity+ORDER+BY+isDeleted+DESC+LIMIT+20
```

and experiment, remove the `ORDER BY`, put filter by date...

```
SELECT Id, Name, isDeleted
FROM Opportunity
WHERE LastModifiedDate >2022-09-01T00:00:00Z
```

There's also dedicated "[data replication API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_get_updated.htm)" which you can use to get opportunities updated / deleted in given time window (imagine an oppty that's edited 3 times in September, once in October - the last modified date will happily say October, how would you retrieve the fact it was touched in September too?). It'll give you just the IDs, you'd have to collect them and send the query for actual data - but it's something.